# Transit through Vancouver International (Round trip US-India-US)

Tags: usa, transit, indian-citizens, canada, vancouver

I would like to fly round-trip from USA to India via Vancouver International and back, on a flight operated by Air Canada (code sharing with United Airlines) in Oct-Nov 2019. I hold a passport from India and a valid multiple entry Canadian Visitor's visa.

1. Would I also need to apply for a Canadian Transit Visa in addition to the Canadian Multiple entry Visitor's visa I already have in order to transit via YVR (layover less than 48 hours)? Or is the Canadian Multiple entry Visitor's visa enough for the transit?
2. Is a layover time of 1h 35m typically enough to go through Canadian immigration at YVR and board the onwards Air Canada flight back to USA?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose we should assume that your immigration documents for the US are also in order.

Comment: @phoog - Yes, immigration documents for the US are in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing temporary resident visa is fine for entering Canada. You don't need a second temporary resident visa just to transit. And you have enough time between your flights.